# Why does Firefox ignore additional arguments to setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout

I just ran into an issue with `setTimeout()` on Firefox that seems like it would be a huge problem if everyone had it, yet I see no mention of it when I search around for it… so I'm wondering if I've screwed this up locally somehow.

The problem is illustrated very clearly by [this W3Schools TryIt page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout_param).  For posterity, the code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the Start button to output "Hello" after 2 seconds.</p>

<p>In this example, we also output the parameters that were passed to the alertFunc() function (does not work in IE9 and earlier).</p>

<button onclick="myStartFunction()">Start</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="demo2" style="color:red;"></p>

<script>
var myVar;

function myStartFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 2000, "First parameter", "Second parameter");
}

function alertFunc(param1, param2) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Hello ";

    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Parameters passed to alertFunc(): <br>" 
    + param1 + "<br>" + param2 + "<br>";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I do this in Chrome (currently `Version 53.0.2785.101 m (64-bit)`, it works.  When I do it in Firefox (currently `48.0.2`), it fails (both parameter values come out as `undefined`).

Comment: works fine in firefox here - w3schools site says `Parameters passed to alertFunc():
First parameter
Second parameter` - is that not what you get?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://imgur.com/a/f4k7J

Comment: `setTimeout(console.log.bind(console), 1000, "hello", "world")` works

Comment: Works fine for me.  (FF 48 on Win 7).  Your FF may be corrupted. Reboot and try again.  Then, if it still fails for you, use profile manager to create a clean FF profile and try again.

Comment: @JaromandaX:  nope  http://i.imgur.com/2ZqhEh8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Turns out [RightToClick](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/) is overriding setTimeout with its own version (which doesn't accept the extra parameters).